# How can one make an IF function to produce a response if it meets the correct string length using tkinter for outputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, tkinter

This small piece of code is part of a much bigger piece, that I am working on using Tkinter. The premise of the coding is to have an input entered, but if it does not reach the minimum string amount, it will reject the code.

```
from tkinter import *

def click():
  entered_text = entry.get()
  output.delete(0.0, END)
  strength = pass_Type[entered_text]    #Key press function
  output.insert(END, strength)


Password = Tk()
Password.title('Password tester') 

label = Label(Password, text="Password:")
label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)    #Entry label

entry = Entry(width=20, bg='light blue')
entry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)     #Entry box

Button(Password, text='SUBMIT',width=5,command=click).grid(row=2,column=0, sticky=W)  #Button

label = Label(Password, text='Strength:')
label.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)          #Output label

output = Text(Password, width=75, height=6, wrap=WORD, background='light blue')
output.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)                              #Output box 

pass_Type = {
 'Password': 'This is a very predicatable password. You should incorporate numbers',
 'password': 'This is a very predicatable password. You should incorporate numbers and capital letters',  #Common password glossary 
 '12345': 'Try and incorporate some letters',
 'qwerty': 'Try to jumble up your letters so the password is not so predictable.'
}

def checkLength(char):
  if len(char) < 3:
    print("length of char is less than len('abc')")
    output.insert(END, 'This is too short')         #Error

password.mainloop()
```

Len('abc') is supposed to give char a minimum of 3 characters.
How can I produce this function so it will reease a statement in my output box when the input does not reach the minimum amount of characters? If I do enter something, it produces the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\", line 1549, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "", line 6, in click
strength = pass_Type[entered_text]    #Key press function
KeyError: 'cd'
```

Is it possible to assign this in a dictionary? (This would make it a lot easier as I already have one made.)

Comment: your use of `Type` is wrong. `type` cant  be shorter than `3` because type is not an integer but rather a way to find if the type of a variable is an `int` or `float` or some other variable type. there for type can not be less than or greater than anything but it can be `==` to the same type. Check out my answer for other option to get what you want done.

Comment: I have updated my answer in regards to the update you made to your question. Please see the updated section of my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

The error you are getting is because your program is looking for the key `cd` in your dictionary when that key does not exist. See my updated answer below.

UPDATE:

Now that you have added the full code I can see the problem.

You need to change the function that checks for password strength to include some `if/elif` statements.

I think it will make more sense once you read the code below:

I have modified your code to deal with the size issue first then the library for the password strength and then a final else statement to perform whatever task you need to do next when the password passes your standards.

```
from tkinter import *

def click():
    entered_text = entry.get()
    if len(entered_text) < 3:
        output.delete(0.0, END)
        output.insert(END, 'This is too short')
    elif entered_text in pass_Type:
        strength = pass_Type[entered_text]
        output.delete(0.0, END)
        output.insert(END, strength)
    else:
        output.delete(0.0, END)
        output.insert(END, "This password is acceptable!")
        # some other commands to perform when password is ok.

Password = Tk()
Password.title('Password tester') 

label = Label(Password, text="Password:")
label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

entry = Entry(width=20, bg='light blue')
entry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

Button(Password, text='SUBMIT',width=5,command=click).grid(row=2,column=0, sticky=W)

label = Label(Password, text='Strength:')
label.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)

output = Text(Password, width=75, height=6, wrap=WORD, background='light blue')
output.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

pass_Type = {
 'Password': 'This is a very predicatable password. You should incorporate numbers',
 'password': 'This is a very predicatable password. You should incorporate numbers and capital letters', 
 '12345': 'Try and incorporate some letters',
 'qwerty': 'Try to jumble up your letters so the password is not so predictable.'
}

Password.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oops,type is my variable. I edited it so it made sense in the context. How can I integrate this into the output for tkinter?

Comment: @matt-333: I have updated my answer. I think you are looking to check of the length of you var `char` is less than the length of `len('abc')`.

Comment: @matt-333: Just checking to see if my answer helped or if you still need help with this issue.

Comment: Thanks for checking up, I apologise for not responding earlier. If I try and test it out on my Tkinter GUI, typing (for example) 'cd,' I get a key error. Can I assign this to a dictionary, or does the dictionary only respond to strings?  Would you like to see the rest of the code?

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File" ",rn self.func(*args)
  File " ", in click
    strength = pass_Type[entered_text]    #Key press function
KeyError: 'cd'

Comment: This error will be hard to resolve without seeing the code in question. You may need to update you question with all the relevant code that can be tested this is why we ask for [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for questions missing key parts of the code for testing.

Comment: @matt-333: Yep. Glad to be able to help

Answer (score -1):

So you want a pop-up box message to appear if the input is less than 3 chars?

`if len(Type) < 3:
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Title of popup Window", "This is where your message 
    goes")`